# How to store the values of n array in one array

Tags: arrays, merge, unique-ptr

I have 1 array that contain n arrays .The structure of array is like this:

```
bigarray(
[array1]=a,b,c,d;
[array2]=[a,c,e]
[array3]=[d,e,f]
)
```

I want to store all the values from the "child" arrays in one array.
like that: `$array=a,b,c,d,a,c,e,d,e,f......`

How can I do that ?

Comment: what language do you speak？

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*Here is the Demonstration for your case in PHP .*/

$array_1 = array("alpha","beta","gamma"); // Array 1
$array_2 = array("hey","hi","hello"); // Array 2
$array_3 = array("apple","ball","cat"); // Array3

$big_array = array($array_1,$array_2,$array_3); // Main Array which is combination of array 1 ,2 and 3
$final_output = array();
$inbetween_output = "";   // Temporay variable
$lastElement = end($big_array); // Check if last element of array
foreach($big_array as $key=>$value){
    $combine = implode(',', $value);   // Implode array values for array 1 , 2 and 3
    $inbetween_output .= $combine;  // storing imploded values in temporary variable
    if($value != $lastElement){ // If last element of array then dont add semi-colon at the end
        $inbetween_output .= ",";
    }
}
$final_output[] = $inbetween_output; // move your data from temporary variable to output array
unset($inbetween_output);  // Release memory occupied by temporary variable
print_r($final_output); 
?>
```